# serial port readline method reads strange characters

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm working on a project to transfer files between two COM ports.
First , I'm taking file name and extension and size before I convert the file to a byte array and send it to the second COM.
the problem is that I get strange characters in the beginning of the first readline method where I'm sending file name, like this :

```
"\0R\0\0\0\0\0\b\0\0\0S\0BAlpha" // file name 
".docx" // file extension
"11360" // file size
```

here is the code I'm using to send the files  :

```
            Send sfile = new Send();
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(op.FileName);
            sfile.Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            int size = sfile.Bytes.Length;
            sfile.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
            sfile.Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReaderbr = new BinaryReader(fs);

            serialPort1.WriteLine(sfile.FileName); // sending file name
            serialPort1.WriteLine(sfile.Extension);// sending extension
            serialPort1.WriteLine(size.ToString());// sending size 


            byte[] b1 = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i <= b1.Length; i++)
            {
                serialPort1.Write(b1, 0, b1.Length);
            }

            br.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            fs.Close();
            serialPort1.Close();
```

and the code below is used to receive data being sent :

```
        string path1 = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        string path2 = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        string path3 =  serialPort1.ReadLine();
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(path3);
        string path0 = @"C:\";
        string fullPath = path0 + path1 + path2;
       // File.Create(fullPath);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create);
        byte[] b1 = new byte[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; i++)
        {
            serialPort1.Read(b1, 0, b1.Length);
        }
        fs.Write(b1, 0, b1.Length);
        fs.Close();
        serialPort1.Close();
```

Comment: A couple things you could add to your post to clarify would include what the *expected* file name should be. This looks like a configuration error, but one thing to try is to, on both sides of the connection, set `serialPort1.DiscardNull = true;` and before you start your reading/writing, call `serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();` and`.DiscardOutBuffer()` to clear your buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing the bytes correctly.  It should be:

```
    byte[] b1 = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    serialPort1.Write(b1, 0, b1.Length);
```

The way you read them is completely wrong as well.  It should be:

```
    byte[] b1 = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; )
    {
        i += serialPort1.Read(b1, i, b1.Length - i);
    }
```